# javascript: image file size is 0 after taking picture from camera video recording option in android 10 using html5 <input type="file">

Tags: javascript, image-upload

After taking a picture using the video recording mode on an Android 10 camera, the image file size is 0 and the image is also broken.
[image]
[image]

I log the e.target.result and there's no base64 string, only "data:"
[image]

Here's my HTML:

```
<button class="btn-file-upload">Upload File</button>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
```

Here's my Javascript:

```
$('.btn-file-upload').on('click', function() {
  $('#file').click();
})
$(document).on('change', '#file', function(event) {
  var allowedTypes = ['image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png'];
  var input = event.target;
  console.log(input.files[0])
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      var blob_url = window.URL.createObjectURL(input.files[0]);
      var text = `
        <div class="text-left">
          type => `+input.files[0].type+` <br>
          size => `+input.files[0].size+` <br>
          name => `+input.files[0].name+` <br>
          <img src="`+blob_url+`" width="100">
        </div>
      `;
      Swal.fire({
        html: text,
        icon: 'warning',
      });
      if(allowedTypes.indexOf(input.files[0].type) != -1) {
        console.log("Valid")
        console.log(e.target.result)  // the result is just "data:" (no base64 string)
      } else {
        console.log("Invalid")
      }
      event.target.value = '';
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
})
```

Here's the sample jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f4zatLoh/1/

Why the size is 0 and the image was broken? How to fix it?

Comment: [unrelated] Why do you use a FileReader here? You don't even use it's result. [related] What browser did you run this code with? Can you reproduce on another one?

Comment: I used chrome on android 10 tablet. I edited, I console log the result, and there's no base64 string, it is just literal "data:".